# Windows Forms mobile application: DataGrid with ComboBox column

Tags: c#, windows, datagrid, combobox, mobile

I'm working on a Windows Mobile 5 application - C# .NET 3.5.

Are you aware of some approach to having a `ComboBox` column within a `DataGrid` ? The user must be able to select certain values on certain rows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your own datagrid column, or find a control suite that has a datagrid with one built in.

there are plenty of examples on how to build the column yourself out there on the web. for example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/RenDataGridComboBoxColumn.aspx

Comment: Derick, it looks like the DataGridComboBoxColumn class is not available in the .NET CF framework.

Comment: That is correct, you'll need to download the code he linked to and add it to your project.